# How can I solve my IndexError issue so I can run my script continuously after wards?

Tags: python, split, ip, indexoutofrangeexception

I am new to python, I learned about this new automation meant to check the network and say when the person you have entered the ip has arrived, I fixed a couple of errors at the beginning but now I am stuck.

```
import sys
import subprocess 
import os
from decouple import config

IP_NETWORK = config('IP_NETWORK')
IP_DEVICE = config('IP_DEVICE')

proc = subprocess.Popen(["ping", IP_NETWORK], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
  line = proc.stdout.readline()
  if not line:
    break
  #the real code does filtering here
  connected_ip = line.decode('utf-8').split()[3]

  if connected_ip == IP_DEVICE:
      subprocess.Popen(["say", "New just connected to the network ! "])
```

I tried to see how split works but I didnt understand

error :

```
file.py", line 15, in <module>
connected_ip = line.decode('utf-8').split()[3]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the output of `line.decode('utf-8')` has less than 4 parts?
In such case, `out of range` error is thrown.